# How can I detect incoming call number in android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am going to develop an Android application using phonegap and jQuery mobile. My thought is on an incoming call, I want to check the phone number in my database and retrieve the details to display the user.

How to detect incoming phone number in phonegap or javascript? Or is there any phonegap api available?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the below link. I am not checked the output. But sure it will work properly

[How to Get the Device's Phone Number Using PhoneGap Android](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-get-devices-phone-number-using.html)

this code explained very well in link

Comment: it only helps to find user phone number only